# SQLite: double primary key and autoincrement

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to define a two-row primary key such that
the second column is autoincremented for each individual
value of the first row.

For instance we would have:

```
X Y
A 1
A 2
A 3
A 4
A 5
B 1
B 2
B 3
C 1
D 1
E 1
E 2
```

I would like to do an:

```
create table t (x text, y integer autoincrement) primary key (x, y);
```

but I get an error from SQLite saying I have an error near "autoincrement". What can I do?
(even an integer valued x would do as long as I can get it to work).

Then I would like to get the above values with:

```
insert into t (x) values ('A');
insert into t (x) values ('A');
insert into t (x) values ('A');
insert into t (x) values ('A');
insert into t (x) values ('A');
insert into t (x) values ('B');
insert into t (x) values ('B');
insert into t (x) values ('B');
insert into t (x) values ('C');
insert into t (x) values ('D');
insert into t (x) values ('E');
insert into t (x) values ('E');
```

THanks,

Jason Posit

Comment: `AUTOINCREMENT` is a keyword you can only use in a column constraint `PRIMARY KEY` clause. I don't have any idea for the actual problem though. What's the issue behind your problem - maybe the problem can be reworked to an easier one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't autoincrement if you have the same number twice or more often in your table. I know what you want to do but it cant be done with autoincrement.

But you could something like
        create table t (x text not null, y integer not null) primary key (x, y);

Also see this: [sqlite: multi-column primary key with an auto increment column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289898/sqlite-multi-column-primary-key-with-an-auto-increment-column)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this from sqlite. What you need is to do this from an upper level, which is your program. The pseudo code would be like:

```
char current_symbol='A';
int count=0;
for(loop all your data)
{
    if(current_symbol == same text)
    {
      count++;    
    }
    else
    {
      current_symbol = same text;
      count=1;
    }

    insert into t (x,y) values ('A', count);
}
```