# composite primary key not updating after save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, composite-primary-key

Here is a minimal test case that forms the basis of my question. Why is it that even though `user` is properly saved, the attribute `user.id` isn't updated? Attempting to re-find the record in the database fetches it without issue and the `id` attribute is properly set.

AFAICT, this is not a matter of trying to auto-increment a composite primary key in sqlite. The same issue occurs with the uuid/PostgreSQL combination as well. The schema only has `id` as the primary key with `[ :account_id, :id ]` being a separate, unique index.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
gem "rails", "~> 5.0.2"
gem "composite_primary_keys"

require "active_record"
require "composite_primary_keys"

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: "sqlite3",
  database: ":memory:"
)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :accounts, force: true do |t|
  end

  create_table :users, force: true do |t|
    t.references :account
    t.index [ :account_id, :id ], unique: true
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_keys = [ :account_id, :id ]
  belongs_to :account, inverse_of: :users
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, inverse_of: :account
end

account = Account.create!
puts "created account: #{account.inspect}"
user = account.users.build
puts "before user.save: #{user.inspect}"
user.save
puts "after user.save: #{user.inspect}"
puts "account.users.first: #{account.users.first.inspect}"
```

And the result of running that script is:

```
~/src
% ./cpk-test.rb
-- create_table(:accounts, {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0036s
-- create_table(:users, {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0009s
created account: #<Account id: 1>
before user.save: #<User id: nil, account_id: 1>
after user.save: #<User id: nil, account_id: 1>
account.users.first: #<User id: 1, account_id: 1>
```

Shouldn't user.id be `[1,1]` after the first save? If this is a bug, who should I report it to?

Comment: I just wanted to give a thumbs up for actually giving a working example in a single file, I wish more questions were this focused.

Comment: Thank you but much thanks is due to Jon Leighton for writing this excellent post on it. http://www.jonathanleighton.com/articles/2011/awesome-active-record-bug-reports/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the answer was a simple one. Rails normally gets the returned primary key from the create and updates the model with it. The composite key doesn't reload on its own so I have to do it. Basically used the logic from `reload` in an after_create hook to fetch the created record and update the attributes accordingly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
gem "rails", "5.0.2"
gem "composite_primary_keys", "9.0.6"

require "active_record"
require "composite_primary_keys"

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: "sqlite3", database: ":memory:")
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :accounts, force: true    
  create_table :users, force: true do |t|
    t.integer :account_id, null: false
    t.string :email, null: false
    t.index [ :account_id, :id ], unique: true
    t.index [ :account_id, :email ], unique: true
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_keys = [ :account_id, :id ]
  belongs_to :account, inverse_of: :users

  after_create do
    self.class.connection.clear_query_cache
    fresh_person = self.class.unscoped {
      self.class.find_by!(account: account, email: email)
    }
    @attributes = fresh_person.instance_variable_get('@attributes')
    @new_record = false
    self
  end
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, inverse_of: :account
end

account = Account.create!
user = account.users.build(email: "#{SecureRandom.hex(4)}@example.com")
puts "before save user: #{user.inspect}"
user.save
puts "after save user: #{user.inspect}"
```

And now:

```
% ./cpk-test.rb
-- create_table(:accounts, {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0045s
-- create_table(:users, {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0009s
before save user: #<User id: nil, account_id: 1, email: "a54c2385@example.com">
after save user: #<User id: 1, account_id: 1, email: "a54c2385@example.com">
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not support auto increment on composite primary key. You may find related questions in SO: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154730/sqlite-multi-primary-key-on-a-table-one-of-them-is-auto-increment), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793205/auto-increment-on-composite-primary-key-sqlite3-python).

Here an @SingleNegationElimination answer from second link:

> In sqlite, you only get autoincrement behavior when only one integer
>   column is the primary key. composite keys prevent autoincrement from
>   taking effect.
>
> You can get a similar result by defining id as the only primary key,
>   but then adding an additional unique constraint on id, col3.

And `composite_primary_keys` keeps that logic.

Also here exists trick to do so: [sqlite: multi-column primary key with an auto increment column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289898/sqlite-multi-column-primary-key-with-an-auto-increment-column)

Comment: I am only using sqlite for ease of demonstrating the issue. I get the same results with UUID and PostgreSQL. The record saves fine and the id is ultimately correct but the instance that `save` is called on isn't updated to reflect the new id after the save is completed.